# Postgres db replication

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

We are using 2 Postgres databases in our application. One for transactions and one for configuration. The sql query that I have to run uses data from both dbs and is a really complex one.

I was using dblink to copy data from the transaction db to the config db on an hourly basis using a shell script running in cron based on the transaction entry timestamp. So, I had all the data in one db (config) and was able to query easily.

But now, if the transactions are updated after being replicated in the config db, I won't have any track of them. The query that I'm using in the script is just dumping transactions based on the timestamp for that hour.

Like if a transaction came in at 13:30 then it would be transferred at 14:00 via the cron job which will pick the transactions having timestamp >= 13:00
and <14:00. But if the transaction was updated at 14:05, I won't have any track of it.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You start talking about schemas and then switch to talking about separate databases. Then you seem to suggest you have stopped copying the data via cron-job but don't mention what you are doing now.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading language.....I'm still copying data via the cron job....but how do I get the transactions in the config db that were copied in the previous timeslot but got updated later. This is my primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the key question is, how do you identify changed (deleted too?) rows in the transaction db? If the answer is "I don't" then you have a problem.

It sounds like you are trying to build a custom trigger-replication system (check out slony/londiste/bucardo). It could well work out less effort to just use a pre-built tool, even though they do more than you seem to want.

However, if your databases are reasonably close (same machine or good network) then it might be worth testing out a [Foreign Data Wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-foreign-data.html) to provide remote access to your transaction db from your config db. It all depends on how often you run your complex query and how much data needs to be dragged between the two databases to service it.

Start here for details of [PostgreSQL Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/different-replication-solutions.html).